# Does "too" always mean "also"?

Tags: commas, too-also

I was told to use a comma before "*too*" when it means "*also*," but doesn't everything mean "*also*" when saying "*too*"? Example:

Person A - "*Do you want a cookie, person B*?"

Person B - "*Yes, thank you*."

Person C - "*I want one, too*."

I've made many more examples in my head, and every time I end a sentence with the word "*too*," it always means "*also*." Does "*too*" always mean "*also*"?

Comment: I'm guessing that they mean to exclude "too" = "excessively", as in "too hot".

Comment: Person A: "I like cake." Person B: "I like it, too." Person A: "Do you?" Person B: "Unfortunately, I like it too much." No time to develop this. Maybe someone else?

Comment: It's also used (particularly, by *children*) as some kind of general-purpose "intensifier" in emphatic assertions: *"I did that!", "No, you didn't!", "Did so too!"*

Comment: Do you believe that _I ate too much_ means _I ate **also** much?_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Too" is a multi-purpose *intensifier* in English.  It can be used to add emphasis to an adjective or adverb: "too fast", "too slow", "too hot", "too cold", etc.  In this way it is used similarly to *very* ("very fast", "very hot) but with a different nuance.  "Too" implies something is "more than" -- more than *expected*, more than is *possible*, more than is *tolerable*, etc.

> We spend too much money.
>
> It's too sweet for me.
>
> They move too quickly for the human eye to follow.
>
> Superman is too strong to defeat with mere bullets.

In your example, "too" is used to emphasize inclusion. As you say, it works like "also".

> She wants to go too.
>
> The boy said he too would like some ice cream.
>
> They normally raise just cattle, but this year they're raising sheep, too.

The comma before "too" is optional.